# Specify lifetime of a reference to a return argument for a member variable in an associated function

Tags: rust

I would like to have a `CatMaker` struct that can create a `Cat`, but stores a reference to it internally so that it can later make calls to that `Cat` (maybe have a `CatMaker.get_child_color(&self)` function).  I believe this implies that the `CatMaker` cannot outlive the `Cat` (otherwise it would try to deference and the `Cat` wouldn't be there) and the compiler seems to agree.

Here is a code example of what I would like to do:

```
pub enum CoatColor {
    Black,
    Tabby,
}

pub struct Cat {
    color: CoatColor,
}

pub struct CatMaker<'a> {
    child: Option<&'a Cat>,
}

impl<'a> CatMaker<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> CatMaker<'a> {
        CatMaker{ child: None }
    }

    pub fn make_cat(&mut self, color: CoatColor) -> Cat {
        let new_cat = Cat{ color: color };
        self.child = Some(&new_cat); // commenting out this line will allow it to compile
        new_cat
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_cat_maker = CatMaker::new();
    let mut my_cat = my_cat_maker.make_cat(CoatColor::Black);
    my_cat.color = CoatColor::Tabby;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify the lifetime of `self.child` in `CatMaker.make_cat`.

Comment: Same root problem as [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423). When you move a value (like returning your `Cat`), the reference to it is no longer valid.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  Seems like the answer may be some thing like [this use of owning_ref](http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/index.html#caching-a-reference-to-a-struct-field)

Answer (score 2):

You can have `CatMaker` own the `Cat`, and `make_cat` return a reference to the `Cat`, rather than returning the `Cat` itself.

```
pub enum CoatColor {
    Black,
    Tabby,
}

pub struct Cat {
    color: CoatColor,
}

pub struct CatMaker {
    child: Option<Cat>,
}

impl CatMaker {
    pub fn new() -> CatMaker {
        CatMaker { child: None }
    }

    pub fn make_cat(&mut self, color: CoatColor) -> &mut Cat {
        let new_cat = Cat { color: color };
        self.child = Some(new_cat);
        self.child.as_mut().unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_cat_maker = CatMaker::new();
    let mut my_cat = my_cat_maker.make_cat(CoatColor::Black);
    my_cat.color = CoatColor::Tabby;
}
```

However, this has a big restriction: you can't use `my_cat_maker` at all as long as you keep the result of `make_cat` around – here, it's stored in `my_cat`, so you can't use `my_cat_maker` until `my_cat` goes out of scope. That's because `my_cat` keeps a mutable borrow on `my_cat_maker`, and Rust doesn't allow two mutable borrows to be usable on the same object at the same time.

If this restriction is not acceptable to you, you'll need to use another tool to manage the lifetime of the `Cat` for you. Such a tool is [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html), which is a reference-counted reference to an object. If you also need to be able to mutate the `Cat`, you'll need to couple `Rc` with [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), which allows mutating the object in an `Rc`.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub enum CoatColor {
    Black,
    Tabby,
}

pub struct Cat {
    color: CoatColor,
}

pub struct CatMaker {
    child: Option<Rc<RefCell<Cat>>>,
}

impl CatMaker {
    pub fn new() -> CatMaker {
        CatMaker { child: None }
    }

    pub fn make_cat(&mut self, color: CoatColor) -> Rc<RefCell<Cat>> {
        let new_cat = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Cat { color: color }));
        self.child = Some(new_cat.clone());
        new_cat
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_cat_maker = CatMaker::new();
    let my_cat = my_cat_maker.make_cat(CoatColor::Black);
    my_cat.borrow_mut().color = CoatColor::Tabby;
}
```

In `make_cat`, the `.clone()` call clones the `Rc` object, which makes a new reference to the same object, incrementing the reference count. When all related `Rc` objects are dropped, the reference-counted object is dropped.

In `main`, we need to call `borrow_mut()` in order to access the `Cat`. `borrow_mut()` returns a `RefMut` object that protects the `Cat` from being further borrowed until the `RefMut` is dropped. If you try to borrow the `Cat` again while a mutable borrow is active, your program will panic.